# How to log in in rest api by php or html or jquery

Tags: php, html, api, rest, curl

I want to log in using test credentials in a rest api...
I found that it can be done in many ways like CURL or jQuery or by the code below but I don't know where to put it or how to do it

```
GET /api.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Authorization: Basic QRTYxmYmdLKimmkLKKKQ==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AuthBasic (your authorization method) is based on HTTP headers. So to authorize you must send in HTTP request properly prepared header, in your example is:

```
Authorization: Basic QRTYxmYmdLKimmkLKKKQ==
```

This string is a base64 encoded string: `$login:$password`. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is wiki desc about AuthBasic.

For this is many methods.

[PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

You must set correct option:

```
$username='ABC';
$password='XYZ';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

---

[Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

You can also use library for this:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://example.com', ['auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']]);
```

---

[Shell cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html):

Here you are setting option `--user`:

```
curl --user name:password http://www.example.com
```

---

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

For ajax requests, you must add in `beforeSend` method correct header:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
};
```